# Border doesn't take the whole table width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, semantic-ui

I added a border at the bottom of the table:

```
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';

<Table id={id || ''} basic="very" className="original-table">
  ...

</Table>
```

in css:

```
.original-table {

    border-bottom: 2px solid #e6e8eb;
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't take the whole table width, there is a little space between the line and the table. The same situation at the right end.

Is there a way to make it touch the table border?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)